# Camera recording with framelayout and surfaceview

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-framelayout

Trying to record video without default camera of android. I found some sample code to fix my solution. Now in that camera previewing orientation in the framelayout is little weired. When I start the record with portrait the preview is landscape and vice-versa.

I tried with setting rotation for both surfaceview and framelayout. Then I tried with setting orientation and nothing worked for me.

My app is to save the recorded video of front facing camera and save it sd card. All are working fine except that orientation problem.

My code goes below,

```
     Layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoview" 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton" 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="REC"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
 Java File:

  public class RecordVideo extends Activity{

private Camera myCamera;
private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

Button myButton;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR | ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    recording = false;

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Get Camera for preview
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if(myCamera == null){
        Toast.makeText(RecordVideo.this, 
                "Fail to get Camera", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
    //myCameraSurfaceView.setO
    FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(recording){
            // stop recording and release camera
            mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

            //Exit after saved
            finish();
        }else{

            //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
            releaseCamera();

            if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                Toast.makeText(RecordVideo.this, 
                        "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

            mediaRecorder.start();
            recording = true;
            myButton.setText("STOP");
        }
    }};

private Camera getCameraInstance(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = null;
        myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (myCamera != null){
        myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        myCamera = null;
    }
}

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
            int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have found another one tutorial to achieve my apps goal. but it was only working in landscape mode, if I rotate it was behaving similar to the old one I put it above. the link is, [Please see this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/android-video-capture-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your issue:

```
    private static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Context mContext, android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info) {
    int rotation = ((MainActivity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        previewRotation = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        previewRotation = (360 - previewRotation) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        previewRotation = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    mCameraInstance.setDisplayOrientation(previewRotation);
}
```